# cordova gradle error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: cordova, gradle

i faced this error building with cordova:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

i have installed gradle 5.3, these are my requirements:

Java JDK: installed 1.8.0

Android SDK: installed true

Android target: installed Google Inc.:Google APIs:17,android-27,android-17

Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-5.3\bin\gradle

how to fix this boring error?! :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an iranian developer, it was all about sunctions ...
Using VPN solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, when I was working behind a company firewall. They did men in the middle, and those site certificates were not signed with the original signature. We had to white-list those addresses. Hope this helps.